# Generate XML for strings of different languages, getting error

Tags: python, xml

I'm writing code to generate an XML with content from different languages strings. I got an error for unicode generation initially, added setdefault command at the beginning, now getting "attributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iter' python". Tried searching but the answers didnt help much.

Here is the traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "oldgood_XliffGenerator.py", line 118, in <module>
    convertToXliff(filename)
  File "oldgood_XliffGenerator.py", line 47, in convertToXliff
    tree.write(destifilename, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 817, in write
    self._root, encoding, default_namespace
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 877, in _namespaces
    for elem in iterate():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 477, in iter
    for e in e.iter(tag):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 477, in iter
    for e in e.iter(tag):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 477, in iter
    for e in e.iter(tag):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 477, in iter
    for e in e.iter(tag):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iter'
```

Code Snippet:

```
def convertToXliff(filename):
    if filename:
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            valid=True
        else:
            print "Could not open "+filename
    else:
        print "no input"

    global fileLength
    root = ET.Element("file")

    global file
    file = ET.SubElement(root, "file")
    file.set("id", generatingLang)
    file.set("native", nativeLang)
    file.set("useAsLocale", setLocale)
    print "Reached stage1"
    datainp = fileRead(filename)
    RecurseObjects(datainp)
    destifilename = "testconvfile.xml"
    #Indent(root)

    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write(destifilename, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

plz check and let me know what Im missing